# Split a string with the \ character in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I am trying to split this string in C#.

```
"FiO2 at 0.40\n36°C-37°C\nFlow at 5 L/min"
```

I have tried using this code:

```
string[] splitVapo = value.Split('\u005c');
```

and this

```
string[] splitVapo = value.Split('\\');
```

But it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `\n` is new line. there is no \ character there. \ is used for escaping. so \\ in string means there is \.

Comment: `var value = "FiO2 at 0.40\n36°C-37°C\nFlow at 5 L/min"; string[] splitVapo = value.Split('\n');` works just fine; `splitVapo.Lenght` is 3

Comment: that worked a treat ASh put it as an answer and be rewarded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` is a single `char` literal though it looks like two characters in the source code

`\n` is a New line escape sequence ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx))

so

```
var value = "FiO2 at 0.40\n36°C-37°C\nFlow at 5 L/min"; 
string[] splitVapo = value.Split('\n');
```

works just fine and `splitVapo.Lenght` is 3

it would have worked also  if you had provided correct hex code for `\n`

```
string[] splitVapo = value.Split('\u000A');
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to split everytime you see `'\n'`, correct? You can try this:

```
string str = "FiO2 at 0.40\n36°C-37°C\nFlow at 5 L/min";            
string[] result = str.Split('\n');
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; ++i) {
    //do something with result[i] if needed
}
```

Comment: Why a new char array of `\n` when Split already takes a character and you only use one?

Comment: @Bauss You are right. Sorry, that was simply my typing habit.

Answer (score 0):

Since `\n` is going to be interpreted as a new line and you cannot change the string, split on `Environment.Newline` itself:

```
string[] splitVapo = value.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

Comment: `Split` already takes a char, so converting it to an array of chars is redundant.